# letra mayúscula automática con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

buenos días hice un código que muestra la primera letra en mayúscula , el problema es que muestra primero la minúscula y luego la mayúscula, podrá mostrar de una vez la mayúscula si en el cambio de transición ?

```js
  

  var input = document.getElementById('requerimiento_solicitar');

  function capitalizarPrimeraLetra() {

  var palabra = input.value;

  if(!input.value) return;

     var mayuscula = palabra.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();

  if (palabra.length > 0) {
      var minuscula = palabra.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }

  input.value = mayuscula.concat(minuscula);
  }
```

```html
   

  <textarea  data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control form-control-sm sin-cambios" title="Por favor describa aquí" placeholder="Por favor describa aquí " id="requerimiento_solicitar" onkeyup="capitalizarPrimeraLetra()" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes usar [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), para capturar el evento de cuando se escriba en la caja, así evitas usar los atributos de eventos en HTML (`onkeyup` por ejemplo), ya que estos ya están obsoletos y son considerados malas prácticas.

Lo que hacemos es obtener el evento de cuando de escriba algo en el `<textarea>`, y obtenemos lo que se ha escrito, ten en cuenta que `const {data} = e` es lo mismo que decir `const data = e.data`. Ahora solo comprobamos que sea la primera letra que se escribe dentro del recuadro y no sea un espacio en blanco, de ser así la convertimos a mayúscula

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById("requerimiento_solicitar");
textarea.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const {data} = e;
  if (textarea.value.length === 1 && data) {
    textarea.value = data.toUpperCase();
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea  data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control form-control-sm sin-cambios" title="Por favor describa aquí" placeholder="Por favor describa aquí " id="requerimiento_solicitar"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar algo así, es un poco más largo, pero permite pegar directamente palabras en minúscula y funciona igual que si se ingresa de a una letra, si se hace la condición del string.lenght = 1 se evita que se repita la función, pero se evita que se ejecute si no se inicia por un único caracter, o sea que al pegar un nombre, o dato X por ejemplo si está en minúscula no funcionará.

```
const inputPalabra = document.getElementById("requerimiento_solicitar");
inputPalabra.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const stringRecibido = inputPalabra.value;
  if (stringRecibido[0] !== stringRecibido[0].toUpperCase()) {
    let letraMayúscula = stringRecibido.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    let restoTexto = stringRecibido.slice(1);
    inputPalabra.value = letraMayúscula + restoTexto;
  }
});
```

Este código funciona sin importar como se ingrese el contenido del input y sin importar su lenght inicial, también tiene una condición para que se ejecute solo una vez, si la primer letra está en minúscula.